# what is actually the difference between prior and evidence?

Tags: probability, bayesian

when saw bayes theorem prior and evidence,  it has similarity to joint probability **(A n B)**. so is there really a clear difference between them???

Comment: It sounds like you are ready for some [Statistical Rethinking](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDcUM9US4XdPz-KxHM4XHt7uUVGWWVSus).

Comment: i want direct answer.

Comment: The question in your title about what is the difference between prior and evidence is an interesting one. Unfortunately I am not a Bayesian, so perhaps not the person to answer that question for you. Bayes theorem, on the other hand, is a theorem about conditional probability and is well regarded in all schools of statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bayes theorem says: $P(A|B) = P(A) \times \frac{P(B|A)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A, B)}{P(B)}$. In this, A is as you say your 'prior belief' and B is your 'evidence'. Bayes theorem thus updates your prior belief with new evidence.

So what does the term $P(A,B)$ mean? As the mathematics show you, it is the same as $P(A) \times P(B|A)$, which contains how strong your prior belief is and how strongly your prior belief supports the new evidence.

Short example: You want to go out for a walk and wonder if you should take an umbrella with you. Your prior belief is that it is going to rain 70% of the time (this is merely a guess that you base on your 'experience', which is subjective, priors can also be objective!). The new evidence (or likelihood) might be checking the forecast of today or looking at the weather for a few hours to see what happens. You now will update your prior belief using this new evidence using Bayes theorem.

So prior belief is what you used to know, evidence is what you gain or collect at the moment to update your prior beliefs.

Comment: i often see that bayes theorem is almost has same concept as confusion matrix which has precision and recall. can P(B) also identified as actual value  and P(A) is identified as predicted value?